# Stray end tag “head” in Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, head

Hi I am trying to vailidate a page. i am getting the error:

```
Line 1, Column 7058: Stray end tag head.
…er:'2045-wpf-id',});});</script></head><body class="custom-background customiz…
```

My webpage source looks like this:

---

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
```

---

Obviously i need this tag but do i need to remove the   tag?
thankyou for any help

> http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Flifeworksphotography.com.au%2Flifeworks%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&outline=1&group=0&No200=1&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices

Comment: would you please share the code snip, where you need help.

Comment: <?php
/**
 * The Header for CreativePearl theme.
 * Displays all of the <header> section
 
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/layout/plugins/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<?php wp_head(); 
?>
</head>

Answer (score 0):

As i checked this [page](http://lifeworksphotography.com.au/lifeworks/), Your `<head>` tag is not opening.

You have to first open the `<head>` tag and then close it before starting the `<body>` tag.

Comment: Hi Paris, i can see the head is source and in my header file? weird? 


<?php
/**
 * The Header for CreativePearl theme.
 * Displays all of the <header> section
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>
<title><?php
 /* Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed. */
 global $page, $paged;
 wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

thanks for your help regards Michael

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code. First, there's this part in your head section:

```
<div id="2045-wpf">
  <a title="Lifeworks Photography Videos" href="http://lifeworksphotography.com.au/lifeworks/video/">
    <img class=" wp-image-730 alignleft" alt="lifeworks photography video" src="http://lifeworksphotography.com.au/lifeworks/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/video22.png" width="20" height="62"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

It isn't allowed to be there and might be the reason why your head breaks and your code won't validate. You should find out which plugin or part of your template is responsible for it and if possible put it where it belongs (I don't know what function it has).

Secondly, there are "Read more" links with this markup:

```
<a href="http://lifeworksphotography.com.au/lifeworks/114-2/" style="font-weight; normal; font-size: 9px;">Read more</a>
```

It's supposed to be "font-weight: normal;". I guess it won't break your template, but it should get fixed too.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Fyn, 

I removed/ disabled WP-float (http://webwiki.co/wp-float/)plugin:
and removed cache and retested the W3 validation and same error exist?
You can tell if the plugin is removed from cache if you can see a floating layer top left with a graphic labeled Video's


<div id="2045-wpf">
  <a title="Lifeworks Photography Videos" href="http://lifeworksphotography.com.au/lifeworks/video/">
    <img class=" wp-image-730 alignleft" alt="lifeworks photography video" src="http://lifeworksphotography.com.au/lifeworks/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/video22.png" width="20" height="62"/>
  </a>
</div>